# SoapClient calling webservice

Tags: php, soap, wsdl, soap-client

I am trying to call a SOAP based webservice. Following is the WSDL for my webservice

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:var="some_namespace">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <var:SomeServiceRequest name="xxx" school="yyy" format="pdf" senderName1="aaa" />
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Now I have tried all the possibilities to call this webservice using the SoapClient class in PHP. I am always getting 'Invalid XML' in response.

Following is the way seems the most obvious but I dont understand why its not working:

```
$soapclient = new SoapClient($this->getWSDLUrl(), array('trace' =>true,
                                                        'soap_version'   => SOAP_1_2,
                                                       ));

$headerbody = array('UsernameToken'=>array('Username'=>'someusername', 
                                            Password'=>'somepassword'));


$header = new SoapHeader('https://xxx/SoapConnector','Security',$headerbody);
$soapclient->__setSoapHeaders($header);
$oResponse = $soapclient->SomeService(array('name'=>'asd', 'school'=>'sdf','format'=>'asdf'));
```

Comment: Can I ask what this `$this->getWSDLUrl()` returns?

Comment: WSDL URL of the webservice...